# How to find out the bundle id for apns's topic

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications

When i try to send message to apns server, it return the `DeviceTokenNotForTopic` error message for me, how to find out the correct topic to fix it? (i also check the app bundle id but not work)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the topic i set is not the same as the certificate bundle id. Login in apple development, go to detail of the certificate page, check the bundle id and see if it is the same as your app's bundle id.